# Add multiple class inside [ngclass]

Tags: angular, angular8

I have searched in SO for the below query but I am not getting correctly how to solve this. on Hover of the mat td cell there will be delete icon. But that delete icon should come only for newly added value so I am trying like below.

```
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" class="
            " style="min-width: 310px !important" [ngClass] = 
            "{'border-orange':element.attrname != 'Total Cost' && element.attrname != 'Overall Cost',  
               'delIcon':element.attrname != 'Total Cost' 
              && element.attrname != 'Overall Cost' 
              && element.attrname != 'Daily Rate'
              && element.attrname != 'Drop Rate'}">
              <span class="dynamiccol " ><i class="far fa-times-circle" (click)="deleteassumption(column)"></i></span>
              {{element.attrname}}
    </td>
```

But I am not getting correct output for this. What can I try next?

Comment: In my opinion the syntax is not correct.. I think you don't need class attribute and you should remove spaces before and after = for [ngClass] this directive should look like this: [ngClass]="{'className': localVariable === 'string'}"

Comment: @MarioBoss i tried like what you said almost there but some thing is missing

Answer (score 0):

You need to deconstruct your conditions and classes in a better way. One way to do so it splitting the classes up via the `[class.foo]="isTrue"` method in Angular. It's just some different way you can add classes if the condition is met.

So in this example, it will add class `foo` to the DOM if `isTrue` condition is met.

Over to your code.

```html
[class.border-orange]="element.attrname != 'Total Cost' && element.attrname != 'Overall Cost'"
```

```html
[class.delIcon]="element.attrname != 'Total Cost' && element.attrname != 'Overall Cost'" && element.attrname != 'Daily Rate' && element.attrname != 'Drop Rate'"
```

which results in:

```html
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" style="min-width: 310px !important" 
[class.border-orange]="element.attrname != 'Total Cost' && element.attrname !== 'Overall Cost'" 
[class.delIcon]="element.attrname != 'Total Cost' && element.attrname != 'Overall Cost'" && element.attrname !='Daily Rate' && element.attrname !='Drop Rate'">
    <span class="dynamiccol">
        <i class="far fa-times-circle" (click)="deleteassumption(column)"></i> 
    </span>
  {{element.attrname}}
</td>
```

Although it is not advised to have so many comparisons inside your HTML template, because it can get messy. Next to that, [strict comparisons](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) might be a better option.